# Issue with openSSL Private Key with modulus error

Tags: ssl, openssl, modulus

I'm new to setting up ssl for curl.  We were given a .cer file and the admin created a private.key.  When we tried to associate the .cer with the private.key, the modulus's don't match.  Is there a way to correct this?  it would be easier to recreate the private.key with the proper modulus but I'm unsure how to do this without wrecking the openssl configuration.

any assistance would be appreciated!
Tom

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something wrong with the process here.  You can't be just 'given' a certificate and then create a private key for it. The process goes like this:

1. You create a private key.
2. You create a certificate signing request (CSR).
3. You submit the CSR to some certificate authority (CA).
4. They verify your identity and then issue you a signed certificate.

The CSR and the signed certificate both contain the public key corresponding to the private key you first created.